# How do I create a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I have 7 separate parameters that I have lists for. Let's call them A, B, C, D, E, F, and G.

All of these parameters will be lists of numbers.

I need to make a csv file that is in this format:

A______B_______C_______D............F

a[0]____b[0]_____c[0]_____d[0].........f[0]

a[1]____b[1]_____c[1]_____d[1].........f[1]

a[2]____b[2]_____c[2]_____d[2].........f[2]

a[3]____b[3]_____c[3]_____d[3].........f[3]

...................................................................

a[-1]___b[-1]_____c[-1]____d[-1]........f[-1]

Unfortunately, these lists won't be a constant length, but will always have the same number of values as each other, so I can't hardcode this.

I did some reading and found that python has an integrated csv library, but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

So how would I use python to create a csv file with the layout above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I couldn't figure out how to use it.* Well, that presupposes you *tried*, but you haven't shown us any of that. What specific problem(s) did you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python3, you can do something like this:

```py
import csv

with open('name.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # header
    writer.writerow(['A', 'B', ..., 'F'])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        writer.writerow([A[i], B[i], ..., F[i]])
```

Comment: I'm trying this out, just wondering - does there need to be two sets of square brackets in the last writer.writerow() line? It seems like you typoed an extra one at the front.

Comment: @aaryan-kainth, can you please upvote the answer =D

Comment: Done! sorry, I forgot to check back here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pandas` library for that:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.DataFrame([A,B,C,D,E,F]).T
table.to_csv("your_file_name.csv",sep="_____")
```